# How can I have both Participants Custom Data and Contacts Custom Data in a Drupal View

Tags: custom-fields, drupal-views

I want to create an Event Participants View which displays both **Participants** Custom Data and **Contacts** Custom Data.

But when I want to add new fields, the **Contact** Custom Data are not proposed.

Isn't this feasible ?

I am on Drupal 5.57 / Civi 4.7.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Relationship (click open the Advanced fieldset on the right side in your View) to bring the Contact data to the party.

Here's how:

1. Create a View: Show **CiviCRM Participants**
2. Relationships: add **CiviCRM Contributions: Contact Record ID**

[image]

3. That will bring the **entire CiviCRM Contact with custom fields** to the party

[image]

Comment: Thk you Karin, but can you be more explicit : when I want to add a relationship, there is no Contact Custom Data Table proposed. (And I don't need a relationship to have the usual Contact Data : they are already included in the Participant View)

Comment: Added some screenshots for you; this will make all Contact Custom Data available

Comment: Waouh ! Great ! But not really self-explanatory. Many thanks Karin

Comment: So you got it working then? Awesome!